# How to incremented in table on button click laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have **Home.blade.php** in which if I click `vote button` it should increment the count in **candidate** table.

**home.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($file as $show)
    <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
       <div class="card">
          <img src="{{$show->image}}"  style="width:100%">
          <div class="card-body">
             <h5 class="title">President</h5>
             <p class="card-text">Name : {{$show->name}}</p>
             <a href="return Homecontroller@Count"> <button>VOTE</button> </a>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**homecontroller**

```
public function Count(){
   DB::table('candidate')->increment('count');
   return view('/home')->with('success', 'voted');
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/home','Homecontroller@Count');
```

Please help me to increment the count, if not this method is there any other method to do the same.

Comment: Your code is correct. What is the issue you facing ?

Comment: Make sure your column `count` is integer in migration.

Comment: Can you please tell if you click on the button then it is called to your controller method or not?

Comment: it gives 404 error

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a better way.

**Add this to Your web.php**

```
Route::put('/votesUp/{vote}', 'HomeController@upVote')->name('votes.upVote');
Route::put('/votesDown/{vote}', 'HomeController@downVote')->name('votes.downVote');
```

in your view list thats is `index.blade.php` add this two buttons

> FORM BUILDER WAY

```
 @foreach($candidates as $item)
<tr>
<td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
<td>{!! $item->name !!}</td>

<td>{!! Form::model($item, ['method' => 'PUT', 'route' => ['votes.upVote',  $item->id ] ,'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data' ]) !!}
{!! Form::submit( 'Up Vote', ['class' => '', 'name' => 'submitbutton', 'value' => 'upvote'])!!}
{!! Form::close() !!}</td>

<td>{!! Form::model($item, ['method' => 'PUT', 'route' => ['votes.downVote',  $item->id ] ,'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data' ]) !!}
{!! Form::submit( 'Down Vote', ['class' => '', 'name' => 'submitbutton', 'value' => 'upvote'])!!}
{!! Form::close() !!}</td>
</tr>    
@endforeach
```

> HTML WAY

```
@foreach($candidates as $item)
<tr>
<td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
<td>{!! $item->name !!}</td>

<td>
    <form method="post" action="{{ route('votes.upVote', $item->id) }}">
        @method('PUT')
        @csrf
        <input class="" name="submitbutton" value="Up Vote" type="submit">
      </form>

        <form method="post" action="{{ route('votes.downVote', $item->id) }}">
        @method('PUT')
        @csrf
        <input class="" name="submitbutton" value="Down Vote" type="submit">
      </form>
</td>
</tr>    
@endforeach
```

I am Considering Your model as `Candidate` so add this to `HomeController`

> ELOQUENT way

```
public function upVote(Request $request, $id)
    {
        Candidate::find($id)->increment('votes_count', 1);
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function downVote(Request $request, $id)
    {
        Candidate::find($id)->decrement('votes_count', 1);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

> DB Facade Way

```
public function upVote(Request $request, $id)
    {
        \DB::table('candidates')->where('id','=',1)->increment('votes_count', 1);
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function downVote(Request $request, $id)
    {
        \DB::table('candidates')->where('id','=',1)->decrement('votes_count', 1);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Explained:

When You click on the upvote button filed `votes_count` in `candidates`  table will be 
**incremented** by 1

When You click on the downvote  button filed `votes_count` in `candidates`  table will be **decremented** by 1

> EDIT FOR undefined variable candidate

Find this line

```
@foreach($candidates as $item)
```

And Replace with

```
@foreach ($file as $item)
```

**FIX FOR**

> Class App\Http\Controllers\HomeController does not exist

From

```
Route::put('/votesUp/{vote}', 'HomeController@upVote')->name('votes.upVote');
Route::put('/votesDown/{vote}', 'HomeController@downVote')->name('votes.downVote');
```

TO

```
Route::put('/votesUp/{vote}', 'Homecontroller@upVote')->name('votes.upVote');
Route::put('/votesDown/{vote}', 'Homecontroller@downVote')->name('votes.downVote');
```

Your Controller Class

> Home**c**ontroller

but i have wrongly written as

> Home**C**ontroller

Comment: thank you so much, but it shows error undefined variable candidate

Comment: thank you i did it, but now m getting this kind of error

Comment: "Class App\Http\Controllers\HomeController does not exist"

Comment: If your issue is fixed then mark the question as answered so in the future it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your column count is integer type in migration
And:

You are writing it in wrong way

```
    <a href="return Homecontroller@Count"> <button>VOTE</button> </a>
```

change it to

```
<a href="{{action(Homecontroller@Count)}}"> <button>VOTE</button> </a>
```

Comment: "Action App\Http\Controllers\Homecontroller@Count not defined. (View: /home/sachin/dd/sjc-voting-system/sjcvoting/resources/views/home.blade.php)"

Comment: Make sure you are giving correct path of controller

Comment: ** <a href="{{action('Homecontroller@Count')}}"> <button>VOTE</button> </a>**

Comment: can you please suggest me any ajax function or javascript for this

Answer (score 0):

The vote button should be like this:

```
<a href="{{ action('Homecontroller@Count' }}"><button>VOTE</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the functionalities like Upvote and Downvote as answered nicely by [@manojkiran-a](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8487424/manojkiran-a) above, I would also add throttling. Now a days it is easy to create a bot which will send upvote requests even when you are using csrf token.

I would add :

```
'middleware' => 'throttle:5'
```

Which will allow only 5 requests per minute per IP address. Not entirely preventing it but making it little harder.

```
Route::put('/votesUp/{vote}', 'Homecontroller@upVote')->middleware('throttle:5')->name('votes.upVote');
Route::put('/votesDown/{vote}', 'Homecontroller@downVote')->middleware('throttle:5')->name('votes.downVote');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your idea.